# task shedule, sharing form label variable

Tags: java, javafx, time, task

I am writting some easy program in Java FX. I am begginer in Java.
I would like make, 
You fill textbox (time in minutes) and run it.
And than it run timer.schedule that it will every minute refresh label with time. Something like stopwatch.
(You set time whitch you want remember time).

I have Controller

```
public class Controller implements Initializable  {

    @FXML
    public Label label;

    @FXML
   private TextField timeEnd;
    .
    .
```

And method onClick

```
@FXML
private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
    Integer timeEndVal = Integer.parseInt(timeEnd.getText());
    Date startDate = new Date();
    Date endDate = new Date();
    endDate.setTime(startDate.getTime() + (timeEndVal * 60000));

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            long currentMinutes = currentTime().getTime() - startDate.getTime();

            System.out.println(currentMinutes / 60000 + " / " + timeEndVal + " min");
            label.setText(String.valueOf(currentMinutes / 60000 + " / " + timeEndVal + " min"));


        }
    }, 0, 60000);
```

But I don't know, how I get `label` variable to `timer.schedule`.
What I do wrong. Thank for helping.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9966136/javafx-periodic-background-task

Answer (score 1):

Here is a non `Controller` version that you can use to get some ideas from. I suggest you use `TimeLine` instead of `Timer`. This is not a complete program!

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class JavaFXApplication267 extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        AtomicInteger timeInSeconds = new AtomicInteger();
        TextField textField = new TextField();
        Label label = new Label(Integer.toString(timeInSeconds.get()));
        Button btn = new Button("Play");

        textField.setPromptText("Enter the number of minutes");
        textField.textProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            //This assume the input is corret!
            timeInSeconds.set(Integer.parseInt(newValue) * 60);//Number of minutes times 60 seconds
            label.setText(getMinsSeconds(timeInSeconds.get()));
        });

        Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), (event) -> {
            if (timeInSeconds.get() > 0) {
                label.setText(getMinsSeconds(timeInSeconds.decrementAndGet()));
            }
        }));
        timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);

        btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
            switch (btn.getText()) {
                case "Play":
                    timeline.play();
                    btn.setText("Pause");
                    textField.setEditable(false);
                    break;
                case "Pause":
                    timeline.pause();
                    btn.setText("Play");
                    textField.setEditable(true);
                    break;
            }
        });

        VBox root = new VBox(label, btn, textField);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    String getMinsSeconds(int seconds)
    {
        return String.format("%02d:%02d", (seconds / 60), (seconds % 60));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what I found. Big thank you.